# How to change one of subsection numbers to a custom letter?

Tags: sectioning, numbering

How to Change one of subsection numbers to something else?;
I want to change:

```
1 Section
 1.1 Subsection      
 ...      
2 Section       
 2.1 Subsection      
 ...     
3 Section       
3.1 Subsection      
...    
4 Section     
4.1 Subsection
```

to:

```
1 Section    
 1.1 Subsection
 ...   
2 Section   
 2.1 Subsection   
 ...  
3 Section  
3.a Subsection   
...   
4 Section   
4.1 Subsection
```

I appreciate your help and time.

Comment: Numbering styles for sectioning headers are generally determined by the document class that's in use, and modifying these numbering styles often depends critically on the specific document class. Thus, please tell us which document class you employ.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using the `article` document class, it suffices to modify the `\thesubsection` macro suitably immediately before the third section, and to restore the default setting before the start of the fourth section.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\blub}{\section{Section}\subsection{Subsection}\dots}

\begin{document}
\blub
\blub

% modify the '\thesubsection' macro
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\alph{subsection}}
\blub

% restore the default
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
\blub
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mico. If I want to remove "3" from 3.a, what I must do? Thanks.

Comment: @Michael - Just run`\renewcommand\thesubsection{\alph{subsection}}` instead of `\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\alph{subsection}}`. (I'm assuming you wish to remove the section-level number *and* the trailing dot, not just the section-level number.)